Unable to see others layers when using a svg file as background Layer
I'm a beginner with OpenLayer and JS in general.
I create a website with this example : https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/svg-layer.html.
I do some modifications to had a vectorLayer as a Waypoint to display on the map. It doesn't works, so i think the specific 'div' and the 'render' function of svgContainer hide all others layers.
I try to replace the svg container of example and add my svg file with a simple function
 import ImageLayer from 'ol/layer/Image';
    import Static from 'ol/source/ImageStatic';
    const imageLayer = new ImageLayer({
      source: new Static({
        url: 'datas/RDC.svg',
        imageExtent: [-180, -337, 284, 180], // Définissez les 
    coordonnées d'étendue appropriées pour votre SVG
      }),
    });

It's works (in this case i can saw my two layers) but the SVG is static, so it is blurred when i'm zooming in.
So i would like to have the svg loaded like the example, to have all calculations for zooming and no resolution lost, but with the ability to add some layers on it, like a simple Waypoint for example.
Globally, if you could show me how to add this :
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/icon.html
on this :
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/svg-layer.html
as a layer, it will be very cool !
Thank you so much,
Raynoxis

You can avoid blurring by loading the SVG image directly as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-image-svg.html
The equivalent code for ImageStatic would be
  import ImageLayer from 'ol/layer/Image.js';
  import ImageSource from 'ol/source/Image.js'
  import {createLoader} from 'ol/source/static.js';
  import {load} from 'ol/Image.js';

    const imageLayer = new ImageLayer({
      source: new ImageSource({
        url: 'datas/RDC.svg',
        imageExtent: [-180, -337, 284, 180], 
        load: load,
      }),
    });

